# Regex between two text elements without capturing those elements? Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

So, I'm writing a google script, and I've been using the regex101 tool to troubleshoot it, but I'm having absolutely no luck.

Here's the regex I need:
Is there a way in JS to isolate "randomstuff" from "myemail+randomstuff@gmail.com" without getting the + or @ included in the returned result?

I've tried using my more limited regex skills to do so, but the end result always includes '+' and '@'.

Comment: I tried, but no luck:
\\+(.*)@

Still returns a result with +randomstuff@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`match function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with captured groups as

```
matched = "myemail+randomstuff@gmail.com".match(/\+(.*?)@/);
matched[1]
// Outputs
// randomstuff
```

- `\+` Matches `+`
- `(.*?)` Matches anything, captured in group 1
- `@` Matches `@`
- `matched[1]` The `match` will return an Array containing the matched results. The contentes of the array will be the captured groups in the regex match along( which are indexed by the the capture group number. Here the group is one hence we used `matched[1]`) and the entire match( indexed by 0)

Answer (score 0):

I used this regex http://regexr.com/3b1fa

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rt4h215g/

```
/\w+(?=@)/g
```

the `(?=@)` uses positive look ahead to check and see when the @ symbol presents itself without including it in the match. Since **+**  isn't considered a word character you can simply use /w+ to get the characters before the **@** symbol and after the **+**.

Answer (score 0):

```
var originalString = "myemail+randomstuff@gmail.com";
/\+([^@]+)@/.exec(originalString )[1];
```

This will return

> "randomstuff"